# PHP and Codeigniter. CURL failure on server but not local machine

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing an API using Codeigniter and Phils RESTserver.
It works perfectly fine on my local machine (mac lion) but on my server (Ubuntu 10.04 with PHP 5.3) I get an error.

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_FAILONERROR - assumed 'CURLOPT_FAILONERROR'

Filename: libraries/REST_Controller.php

Line Number: 717
```

The line in the REST_controller.php file at line 717.

```
$verify = $CI->curl->simple_get($verify_uri, array(), array(CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => FALSE));
```

What is wrong? Is there something that I need to upgrade?

Comment: seems that the CURLOPT_FAILONERROR constant cannot be found. 
Maybe the curl module is not insalled/enabled on your pdouction system.
I don't know the CI  implementation, but maybe you can find a tip here: http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Comment: Can you post phpinfo's output related to cURL from your server? The fastest way is issuing 'php -i|grep curl' command from console, I think

Comment: Running you command gives me nothing. Perhaps CURL is not installed? php -i|grep curl
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: I activated CURL extension and now I got another error instead: curl_setopt_array(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set

Comment: the message could not be more explicit ;)

Comment: Check that your server php interpreter is not in safe_mode: `php -i|grep safe' If so - modify php.ini to disable it. Also, see http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php

Answer (score 0):

change `array(CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => FALSE)` to `array("CURLOPT_FAILONERROR" => FALSE)` to get rid of the notice about "Use of undefined constant"